Any way to see what URL's my computer is requesting to put in INetCache?
Apps like SearchApp.exe use URLs to use svg files for icons and such as well as pngs for pictures. Is there any way to see what URL's are connected to these files? They always end up in "C:\Users*user*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE"
There has to be a way to intercept the requests that place them there right? And I am not referring to locations on the drive I am referring to locations on the internet.
